# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzv$zzb.class

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-audience-network

When I add the facebook dependencies in the app I get this error

//firebase

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'


//facebook
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.15.0'




Error:Execution failed for task ':websites:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzv$zzb.class
```

When I remote facebook dependencies the app runs fine ? How do I solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You are including 2 different versions of the following libraries in your app `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0`

FirebaseUI-Android 0.4.0 uses version `9.0.0` of those libraries and you are including version `9.0.4` in your apk has well.

You can fix that by using the most recent version of FirebaseUI-Android

```
dependencies {
// Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.1'

// FirebaseUI Database only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.5.1'

// FirebaseUI Auth only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.5.1'
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Comment: Though you are right about firebase libraries. Removing facebook libraries fixes the issue when generating release apk.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook SDK libaries have a puzzling (at least to me) dependency on the old library `play-services-ads:8.4.0` ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152854/4815718)).  Add this to your dependencies to cause the more recent version to be used instead of 8.4.0:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.15.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```