# Facebook android sdk dependency conflict

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-facebook

I am using `facebook-android-sdk:4.20.+` and `com.android.support` libraries which are conflicting with error message:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.2.0, 25.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 and com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0 less... (⌘F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
```

Following are my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.4'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

On running a gradle dependency report using:    `./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile`, following are the results for `facebook-android-sdk`.

```
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+ -> 4.20.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|              \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
```

What is the right combination of dependencies that I must use?

Comment: I think this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354359/gradle-error-after-including-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your specific case the problem is because the facebook sdk has a dependency with `com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0` and that version is old and your current version of the support library is **25.2.0**.

As you can see on the dependency graph the newer versions of cardview-v7, appcompat-v7 and support-v4 are already being used, so you can try adding:

> compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'

to the dependencies so that the newer version of customtabs is used also by the facebook sdk.

This answer could be useful also: [Gradle error after including facebook sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354359/gradle-error-after-including-facebook-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer didn't solve my problem. But based on this response [Facebook SDK dependency conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212449/facebook-sdk-dependency-conflict) it works.